# how can i fix this to got the correct result for temperature

Tags: java, eclipse

**its gives me wrong result if i use number more then 1**

```
   try {
    double celsius = Double.valueOf (editCelsius.getText().toString());
    double fahrenheit = celsius * 33.8 ;
    double kelvin = celsius * 274.15
```

Comment: better could be to use conponent accepting only numbers instead of parsing, question in this form isn't answerable

Comment: You should look up the correct formulas to convert temperature, wiki might be a start?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your formulas are not even good with input of 1... You have the formulas *very* wrong... This is the correct implementation:

```
double celsius = Double.valueOf (editCelsius.getText().toString());
double fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32 ;
double kelvin = celsius + 273.15;
```

**A word of advice:** *always* apply common sense... I think everyone knows that water boils at 100 degrees Celsius, and 212 degrees Fahrenheit, and freezes at 0 degrees Celsius and 32 degrees Fahrenheit. From this, you should have been able to devise the formulas for Fahrenheit calculation... And at least you would have been able to tell that your formulas are not good.

Recommended reading:

- [Conversion of units of temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_units_of_temperature)

Comment: thanks i knew my formula is not good but in your formula the kelvin is still wrong

Comment: `thanks i knew my formula is not good ` Then why didn't you fix it _before_ asking?

Comment: i didn't knew that it was wrong ... you told me its wrong and i am thanksfull for that. i thought it was some thing wrong with the way i used. that's why i asked and you answered. and thanks again man ... you are my hero

Comment: the kelvin have to be + not -

Comment: @aloneexcite Thanks, I first had it that way, but then my brain went out of control and edited it to -... Seems I need some rest...